# Python - Ask for input multiple times til a certain input disables it

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input

I am trying to write a function that makes a list.
The function requires user input.
The function will prompt for input in which user input an element.
That element will be added to the list.
When user input a certain element i.e. a string, the function returns the list.

So when I run the function, it should be something like this:

```
Input an element: 100
Input an element: 200
Input an element: 300
Input an element: Stop
[100, 200, 300]
```

So far this is my progress:

```
def list_maker():
    """Make a list from input"""
    result = []
    def main():
        element = input("Input an element: ")
        if element == "Stop":
            print(result)
        else:
            main()
    main()

list_maker()
```

Comment: What do you want to do when `element != "Stop"`?  ([hint 1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types), [hint 2](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=append))

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I'd do what you want to achieve:

```
final_list = []
while 1:
    user_input = input("Input an element: ")
    if user_input == "Stop":
        break
    final_list.append(user_input)

print(final_list)
```

To incorporate this into your existing code:

```
def list_maker():
    """Make a list from input"""
    result = []
    while 1:
        user_input = input("Input an element: ")
        if user_input == "Stop":
            break
        result.append(user_input)
    print(result)

list_maker()
```

This `while` loop goes on until the `if` statement inside triggers. The `break` inside the `if` causes the loop to exit, and then does whatever is after the loop.

This is how it looks when you run the program:

```
Input an element: 100
Input an element: 200
Input an element: 300
Input an element: Stop
[100, 200, 300]
```

---

The method that you tried wasn't working is because you never actually added `element` to the `result` list. If you still wanted to use a recursive solution rather than a `while` loop, just add a line of code that appends `element` to the list:

```
def list_maker():
    """Make a list from input"""
    result = []
    def main():
        element = input("Input an element: ")
        if element == "Stop":
            print(result)
        else:
            result.append(element) # Added
            main()
    main()

list_maker()
```

Comment: Interesting, I'm still learning from the beginning, I've no idea what break does. What if I want it to produce a tuple instead of a list?

Comment: @Oulchura `break` escapes from a loop. If you are inside a `for` or `while` loop and the interpreter hits a `break` statement, it immediately exits the `for` or `while` loop and starts running the code after it. You can read more about it [here on the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

Comment: I just realized it returns strings, what I am looking for are actually int or floats. What could I do?

Comment: @Oulchura Call `float` or `int` on `element` just before you append it. So change `result.append(element)` to `result.append(float(element))` or `result.append(int(element))`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a break, nor do you need to do this recursively. Keep it simple:

```
def list_maker(result):
    """Make a list from input"""
    element = input("Input an element: ")
    while element != "Stop":
        result.append(int(element))  # In your example you listed numbers, not strings, the int() function will turn the element into a number
        element = input("Input an element: ")

result = []
list_maker(result)
print(result)
```

If you want the result to exist outside of the function, you need to declare it outside the function. Lists are mutable, which means the append function will actually change the result list inside the function. That way you can print it out after the list_maker has run. You might want to make it easier  for the user to quit. Update the while line to this and it will exit if they don't type in a number:

```
while element.isdigit():
```